# UIPopoverController - display without title bar?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Hoping there is a way to do this. Would like to just display the border around the view, with no 40px title bar at the top. Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered... I was initializing it with a Navigation Controller. Once I removed that I didn't get the title bar.